# Loop through files in all directories in vb

Tags: vb.net

WIth below code I'm trying to loop through all .prt files in all directories, but getting error:

> file is a type and cannot be used as expression.

Code:

```
    Dim PartsPath as string = "D:\workdir\1"
    '''' Get file size
    Dim strFileSize As String = ""
    Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(PartsPath)
    Dim aryFi As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*.prt")
    Dim fi As IO.FileInfo
    Dim f1 as integer = f
    For Each fi In aryFi
        strFileSize = (fi.Length / 1048576).ToString()
        objExcel.cells(f1, 4).value = FormatNumber(strFileSize, 2)
        f1 = f1 + 1
    Next

    For Each file In di.GetFiles("*.prt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Comment: Change the name of the "file" variable to something else. File is a type. VB doesn't know what you mean.

Comment: Same error. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't complete, because it's missing the body of the For Each and the error was probably in there or after it.

I was able to reproduce an error like it (https://dotnetfiddle.net/kEYcvv), and I think it was that you carried on using the `file` variable outside the loop where it was declared. As a result, the variable didn't exist any more so VB switched to thinking you were talking about the shared [System.IO.File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netcore-3.1) class used for things like `File.Exists("c:\temp\testfile.txt")`. One of the downsides of vb not being case sensitive! See this image:

[image]

You're using System.IO.FileInfo classes which are instance versions of using File. These are two ends to the same stick:

```
Dim f as New FileInfo("c:\temp\testfile.txt")
If f.Exists Then ...

If File.Exists("c:\temp\testfile.txt")
```

Sometimes people use Directory.GetFiles which returns arrays of string paths, other times they use DirectoryInfo.GetFiles which returns FileInfo objects. The latter is arguably easier to use if one is accessing a lot of info about the file like its name, path, length, date etc. Often for quick queries like "does this file, referenced by this string path, exist?" it's more handy to use File.Exists rather than make a new FileInfo then query its existence

All in, be aware that VB will interpret your use of "file" either as a variable called "file" if such a variable is available, or as the shared class File. I recommend you just change the name of the variable (because you can't rename the System.IO.File class and you have to Imports System.IO so your other stuff will work) to something else. Because VB isn't case sensitive like C# it's a lot easier to accidentally use variable names (which should start with a lowercase letter) in places where class (type) names (which should start with an uppercase letter) are expected and vice versa.

For this lack-of-case-sensitivity reason always strive to avoid ever calling a variable the same name as a Type, in VB

Answer (score 1):

Worked when changed code line as below:

```
 For Each fi In di.GetFiles("*.prt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Accessed filename with `fi.FullName`